# SwiftUI View with variadic generics

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui

For some reason Xcode can't build SwiftUI views with variadic generics (parameter pack). The new Swift 5.9 feature.

Sample code is:

```
struct CustomView<each T>: View {
    var body: some View {
        Color.red
    }
}
```

Error message is empty but sometimes it's possible to get a common error with no details in log:

```
Command SwiftEmitModule failed with a nonzero exit code
```

What I'm doing wrong?
Xcode versions: 15.1.0 beta 3 and 15.0 RC

Comment: @matt Take a look at this App Developer video: https://developer.apple.com/wwdc23/10168

Comment: I see — and do we think that this feature has gone final?